# Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Need to Load a json dataset into hive and perform some cleaning operations.

This is how my Json Dataset looks -

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a1321d5741a2384e802c552"},"reviewerID":"A3HVRXV0LVJN7","asin":"0110400550","reviewerName":"BiancaNicole","helpful":[4,4],"reviewText":"Best phone case ever . Everywhere I go I get a ton of compliments on it. It was in perfect condition as well.","overall":5.0,"summary":"A++++","unixReviewTime":1358035200,"reviewTime":"01 13, 2013","category":"Cell_Phones_and_Accessories","class":1.0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a1321d5741a2384e802c557"},"reviewerID":"A1BJGDS0L1IO6I","asin":"0110400550","reviewerName":"cf \"t\"","helpful":[0,3],"reviewText":"ITEM NOT SENT from Blue Top Company in Hong Kong and it's been over two months!  I will report this.  DO NOT use this company.  Not happy at all!","overall":1.0,"summary":"ITEM NOT SENT!!","unixReviewTime":1359504000,"reviewTime":"01 30, 2013","category":"Cell_Phones_and_Accessories","class":0.0}
```

Added JsonSerDe jar:
`add jar 'gs://bucket_spam_ham/jars/hive-hcatalog-core-3.1.0.jar';`

Code I used for creating a table;

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spam_dataset(`_id` struct<`$oid`:string>,reviewerID string,asin string,reviewerName string,helpful array<int>,reviewText string,overall float,summary string,unixReviewTime bigint,reviewTime string,category string,class float)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
load data inpath 'gs://bucket_spam_ham/dataset/Cell_Phones_and_Accessories.json' into table spam_test;
```

But when I try to do a count getting the following error.

```
select count(*) from spam_dataset;
Query ID = vikaspattathe_20221106230048_8c0ecb98-1a29-4988-b699-b5d73144b996
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1667774058655_0007, Tracking URL = http://spam-ham-m:8088/proxy/application_1667774058655_0007/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/mapred job  -kill job_1667774058655_0007
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 10; number of reducers: 1
2022-11-06 23:00:57,733 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2022-11-06 23:01:16,162 Stage-1 map = 10%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 12.2 sec
2022-11-06 23:01:17,201 Stage-1 map = 30%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 38.25 sec
2022-11-06 23:01:19,245 Stage-1 map = 43%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 85.25 sec
2022-11-06 23:01:20,270 Stage-1 map = 63%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 88.81 sec
2022-11-06 23:01:21,291 Stage-1 map = 70%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 90.2 sec
2022-11-06 23:01:43,822 Stage-1 map = 80%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 90.2 sec
2022-11-06 23:01:44,842 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 90.2 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 minutes 30 seconds 200 msec
Ended Job = job_1667774058655_0007 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1667774058655_0007_m_000001 (and more) from job job_1667774058655_0007
Examining task ID: task_1667774058655_0007_m_000007 (and more) from job job_1667774058655_0007

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1667774058655_0007_m_000007

URL:
  http://spam-ham-m:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1667774058655_0007&tipid=task_1667774058655_0007_m_000007
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:204)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapRunner.run(ExecMapRunner.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:973)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:195)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('Y' (code 89)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@e1e2e5e; line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe.deserialize(JsonSerDe.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:936)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('Y' (code 89)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@e1e2e5e; line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:2090)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._nextTokenNotInObject(Utf8StreamParser.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:492)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe.deserialize(JsonSerDe.java:169)
        ... 11 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 10  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 90.2 sec   HDFS Read: 1879160542 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 minutes 30 seconds 200 msec
```

The query is able to run successfully for a subset(first 10 rows) of the same dataset.

Comment: Open the Tez UI to find the real error

Comment: I'm using hive on a GCP cluster. Can I install Tez UI on it from commandline?

Comment: You should already have it installed as part of the cluster

Comment: I'm getting a different error after I set hive.execution.engine=mr. Edited the op to reflect the same.

Comment: You should always prefer Tez over MapReduce. Again, you still need to go to the YARN UI + logs to find the real error for Mapreduce tasks. Or, as the error there, says, your JSON isn't able to be parsed. E.g. `line 1, column 2` (the second character of some file in your table), it got `character 'Y'` ... From what you've shown, that does not match that JSON data